# Improper integral criterion

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

im trying to solve the following by the limit comparison theorem.

**Problem:**
$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^{3/2}(1-x)^{2/3}}dx$ is convergent or divergent?

since its a type II with 2 indeterminations  I can split them and test them individually. Now, by the limit comparison test its easy to show that $\int_{1/2}^{1} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^{3/2}(1-x)^{2/3}}\,dx$ is convergent cause we can compare with $\int_{1/2}^{1} \frac{1}{(1-x)^{2/3}}\,dx$ which is convergent and $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\tfrac{\sin(x)}{x^{3/2}(1-x)^{2/3}}}{\tfrac{1}{(1-x)^{2/3}}}=\frac{\sin(1)}{x^{3/2}}=1$ then $\int_{1/2}^{1} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^{3/2}(1-x)^{2/3}}\,dx$ converges.

Now, for the other one, $\int_{0}^{1/2} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^{3/2}(1-x)^{2/3}}\,dx$, I know I can pick $g(x)=\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}$ and it will diverge, but if I take $h(x)=\frac{1}{x^{1/2}}$ it will converge. **Which one should I pick and why?**

Comment: Do you know the value of $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$?

Comment: Near $x=0$ the integrand is $\sim x^{-1/2}$.

Comment: Taking your $g$, the ratio limit is $0$ -- which is inconclusive as the integral of $g$ over $(0,1/2]$ diverges. The better choice is $h$.

Comment: MMA gives the following result: $$\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{1}{3}\right) \,
   _2F_3\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4};\frac{5}{12},
   \frac{11}{12},\frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{4}\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)}$$

Comment: Which is the Taylor expansion of $\sin x\ /\ (1-x)^{2/3}$ near zero?!